# Does pandas .to_csv export cells properly (with no data loss) if it contains more than 32,767 characters?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

Before I say anything, please note that it is MANDATORY for me to use xlsx or csv as it's for a website import and the information in a cell CAN NOT be truncated or removed or shortened in any way. Please do not provide an answer to which says to use something else, because I can't.

I'm exporting data to a spreadsheet which can either be csv or xlsx depending on what answer I find to this question, and over 10000 rows contain a cell which has MORE than 32,767 characters. (So the total characters would be 32767+ * 10000). for example: (89473 characters * 10000)

I'm not sure whether or not the information retains once it has completed an export because in Excel it either cuts (removes) the data in cells at 32,767 characters for an xlsx, or for a csv export, it puts information in to the next rows and makes it look corrupted (even though it probably isn't).

My main question is: Is the information retained after an export from pandas and just doesn't show the info in excel, but instead the raw file contains that info? Or does everything just get cut off after export no matter what?

Also, is there any way to view the full amount of characters in the cells using a different program, because, obviously, Excel cuts it off or makes it look distorted.

I have tried looking online for solutions and have had no luck. I am able to use these other formats (besides from csv and xlsx) for importing to the website: XLS, XML, or ZIP File.

`df.to_excel('File.xlsx') ##Using this to export the file.`

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: 10 seconds on google tells me that [Excel has a hard limit of 32767 characters per cell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). So this is excel's problem.

Aight, lets make a test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
bigstring = "".join(["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] * 10000)
df = pd.DataFrame([bigstring, bigstring[:-1], bigstring[:-2]])
```

Looks good so far

```
>>> list(map(len, df[0]))
[260000, 259999, 259998]
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Now let's see if it worked:

```
wc -l test.csv 
4 test.csv
```

4 lines, that's correct.

```
awk '{ print length }' test.csv 
2
260002
260001
260000
```

Length per line is all good too.

```
cat test.csv | grep -o '...$'
XYZ
WXY
VWX
```

Yep, looks good. So I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was annotating generated data in Excel when some sentences were "cut off". Thought it was a problem during data generation, but it's just Excel's display limitation.